# making multiple sliders with one set of jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a slider with jQuery using html tags which have classes instead of IDs so that I will be able to use the same jQuery code for other duplicated sliders.

The problem is, I want the width of my `ul` to be calculated based on the number of `li`s, instead of setting it manually in CSS.  When there is only one slider I can set my vars outside of the function, but when I have to use it though event attributes on my html parts so that I will be able to use them for multiple sliders, I have to move the vars inside of my function, which sets the wrong width.

This is my code:

```
 function OLAR(direction,span) {
        var OurNexNPrv = $(span);
        var Parent_OLAR = OurNexNPrv.parents('.OLAR');
        var UL_OF_OLAR = Parent_OLAR.find('.OLAR_CONTENT ul');
        var LI_OF_OLAR = UL_OF_OLAR.find('li');
        var LI_OF_OLAR_LENGTH = LI_OF_OLAR.length;
        var Quantity_OF_OLAR_PAGES = LI_OF_OLAR_LENGTH / 3;
        var Max_Margin_LEFT = -(Quantity_OF_OLAR_PAGES - 1) * 576;
        UL_OF_OLAR.css('width',LI_OF_OLAR_LENGTH*192);

        var AffectedLeftMargin;
        var CurrentLeftMargin = UL_OF_OLAR.css('margin-left');

        CurrentLeftMargin = parseFloat(CurrentLeftMargin);

        if (direction == 'right') {
            AffectedLeftMargin = CurrentLeftMargin - 576;
        }
        if (direction == 'left') {
            AffectedLeftMargin = CurrentLeftMargin + 576;
        }

        if (AffectedLeftMargin < Max_Margin_LEFT) {
            AffectedLeftMargin = 0;
        }

        if (AffectedLeftMargin > 0) {
            AffectedLeftMargin = Max_Margin_LEFT;
        }

        UL_OF_OLAR.animate({'marginLeft': AffectedLeftMargin}, 1000);
    }

    $('.CIRCLE_LOAD_RIGHT').click(function () {
        OLAR('right');
    });

    $('.CIRCLE_LOAD_LEFT').click(function () {
        OLAR('left');
    });
```

How can I set the width for each of my `ul`s individually, through css commands outside of that function?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my ul tag did not have the absolute position; after giving it the right position and left:0 and bottom:0 or right:0 and bottom:0 (based on your language)the given width which comes from JQuery code can rhyme perfectly with everything else. I've tried it with multiple sliders and it works perfectly :)
So, we need an anchor point in order to make this work. And there is nothing wrong with this JQuery code which has been mentioned above!
Have a great day.